# Cant connect my pi 4 automatically by using only the bootfile on the sd card

Tags: wifi, boot, sd-card

Im trying to connect my pi 4 to the wifi via editing the boot file on the sd card. the wifi is a hidden network
The following i tried to do, see picture.

the file name is [wpa_supplicant.conf]
i added this file on the sd

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=NL
network={
  ssid="Hyperloop 2.4g"
  scan_ssid=1
  key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
  psk="xxxmywifipaswordxxx"
}
```

Im wondering what i do wrong because i cant find the device on the network. I use an app to find devices that are connected to the network.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Check [this link](https://gist.github.com/windows98SE/8a8a59cc5d5d9d0b2ed2) out if it has secured by WPA2.

Comment: Let me guess. UDelft?

Comment: And by no GUI, does that mean you have terminal access? You could use `wpa_cli` to setup your connection.

Comment: @Swedgin , yes im studying at the TU Delft. But i wanna program my own bitcoin node.

Comment: Haha the `hyperloop` and `NL` gave it away. But do you have terminal access or is the pi running headless?; No GUI is not the same as headless

Comment: @Swedgin , Im running booster lite no the raspberry pi. or atleast, i try to. I cant get in to the terminal. Im just trying to configure the sd card like that so it will connect to the wifi. I think i have to edit the [wpa_supplicant.conf] file

Comment: @M.Rostami i tried this but it is still not working :(. i think i will let my nerd roommate friend fix this stuff

Comment: In the title you told us that you run a Raspberry Pi 4B but in a comment you say: "*Im running booster lite no the raspberry pi*". What are you running now? What is this booster lite device?